# Convert a JS kind-of-class to real class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I found that in my project and I would love to improve it, by implementing a real class.

```
const Fetch = {};

function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response;
  } else {
      const error = new Error(response.statusText);
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
  }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
    return response.json();
}

/**
* @function
* @name Fetch
*/
Fetch.Fetch = (src, options = {}) => {
  return window.fetch(src, options)
    .then(checkStatus);
}

/**
* @function
* @name FetchJSON
*/
Fetch.FetchJSON = (src, options = {}) => {
  return window.fetch(src, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON);
}

/**
* @function
* @name GetJSON
*/
Fetch.GetJSON = (src, options = {}) => {
  options = Object.assign({}, options, {
    method: 'GET'
  });

  return Fetch.FetchJSON(src, options);
}

Fetch.GetApiJSON = (src, options = {}) => {
  options = Object.assign({}, options, {
    headers: {
      'some-info': 'your header'
    }
  });

  return Fetch.GetJSON(src, options);
}

module.exports = Fetch;
```

I'm aware that is not the way to create class, and I would love to convert it that way. But I'm a bit confused for those kind of helpers.

What do you think of having something like that :

```
new Fetch(url, options).Fetch();
new Fetch(url, options).GetJSON();
```

I could used promises, that way.
In brief, what do you think that would be the best way ?

Comment: Right now you have a bunch of methods attached to an object. If you don't want/need multiple instances of something then that's a perfectly acceptable way of doing so. If you want to be able to create multiple instances of it then you'll need to create a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to implement a fluent interface. It may be simplest to demonstrate by example:

```
const req = new Fetch('http://example.com');

req.get().then(handleResponse);
// -> calls window.fetch('http://example.com', { method: 'GET' })

const req2 = req.headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/csv' });

req2.get().then(handleResponse);
// -> calls window.fetch('http://example.com', {
//            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/csv' },
//            method: 'GET' })

req2.options({ mode: 'no-cors' }).get().then(handleReponse);
// -> calls window.fetch('http://example.com', {
//            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/csv' },
//            mode: 'no-cors',
//            method: 'GET' })
```

You get the idea. Each method call returns a new object that we can either make a request with, or call additional methods on to add options, headers, etc. (or both).

An implementation would look something like this. I've stubbed out `window.fetch` so it just logs some information to show you the result.

```js
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  } else {
    const error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}

function mergeOptions(...options) {
  const headers = Object.assign({}, ...options.map(({headers}) => headers));
  return Object.assign({}, ...options, { headers });
}

class Fetch {
  constructor(url, options={}) {
    this.url = url;
    this._options = options;
  }

  options(opts={}) {
    return new Fetch(this.url, mergeOptions(this._options, opts));
  }
  
  headers(headers={}) {
    return this.options({ headers });
  }

  fetch() {
    return window.fetch(this.url, this._options).then(checkStatus);
  }

  get() {
    return this.options({ method: 'GET' }).fetch();
  }
  
  getJSON() {
    return this.get().then(parseJSON);
  }
  
  getApiJSON() {
    return this.headers({ 'some-info': 'your header' }).getJSON();
  }
}

// Stub this out for demonstration
window.fetch = (...args) => {
  console.log('Called window.fetch with args', args);
  return Promise.resolve({
    status: 200,
    json() { return { hello: 'world' }; }
  });
}
function logResponse(res) { console.log('Got response', res); }

// Create a Fetch object
const req = new Fetch('http://example.com');

// Do a basic fetch
req.fetch().then(logResponse);

// Add some options to previous
const reqWithNoCache = req.options({ cache: 'no-cache' });

reqWithNoCache.fetch().then(logResponse);

// Add some headers to previous
const reqWithNoCacheAndHeader = reqWithNoCache.headers({ 'Accept-Language': 'en-US' });

reqWithNoCacheAndHeader.fetch().then(logResponse);

// Use convenience method with previous
reqWithNoCacheAndHeader.getApiJSON().then(logResponse);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```